# What is Electromagnet and inductor?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, inductance, magnetics, electromagnetic

Explain electromagnet vs inductor? does inductance happens in electromagnet?

Comment: Can you please explain you exact question, show how you have researched on your own, and where your confusion is?

Comment: They are one and the same.

Comment: question is electromagnet loss magnetic field as we cut current

Comment: then answer is "yes"

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html#c1

Comment: But inductance not happens in electromagnet ?

Comment: I'll second Jasen. The answer is simply "yes".

Comment: So inductance happens or not please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

An inductor is designed to keep as much of its field internal as possible, both for efficiency and so that it doesn't disturb other things nearby.

An electromagnet is designed so that part of its field runs externally, to do something useful to something nearby.

They both have inductance. If you connect a voltage source, the current will build slowly. If you try to turn off the current rapidly, it will generate a large voltage spike which, if it has enough energy, must be dealt with or it will cause damage.